# How can I get a text colour to black/white when background changes for max contrast?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to achieve a similiar effect to the e-mail element on this website:https://madebyshape.co.uk/

```
.custom-blend-mode {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

So I got this to work but it changes to the opposite colour, however I would like it to be only black or white for max contrast.

Comment: The hand at the very bottom right? That actually always has a background color set in **.bg-gray-100**. You just can't see it when the website's background is the same color as the element's background color

Comment: @imvain2 no the e-mail on the left, if you notice it changes to white when you scroll onto a black background

Comment: @Playejdhs Their website is made by using Tailwind CSS. See [this playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/nLUPaD02pU) for the exact same code. The same exact code will need to use their font too (Which is called "Circular", a custom font I I guess). To convert that to native CSS, go to [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) documentation, study the classes (like `text-base`), and convert them to native CSS. You're welcome ;)

Comment: @Playejdhs you can ignore that about tailwind. The website might use tailwind but it doesn't actually solve your problem nor even remotely provide an answer. mix-blend works well for backgrounds of white/black. However, if you want a true black/white contrast, you might need to go another route like detecting if the text is above a specific element and applying a class via javascript. But even that won't work because it won't affect only the part that is over the element.

Comment: The example you provided only does black/white alternating because the background is black/white. You can see when the text goes over an image it gains color, or if you change the bg color it is no longer b&w.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to achieve what you are requesting. On the website you linked, the text is not grayscaled. If you set the background of a part of the website to blue and scroll there, the e-mail text gets yellow.

**EDIT:**
With the following approach the text is unable to determine its background on its own. It can only invert the background of the parent element dynamically. So you can't use this approach to get the exact result like on the page you linked. Sorry for that.
This approach is focused on changing backgrounds or having high contrast text in front of a background image with different colors.

You can try this one out:

```css
div {
  background-color: #af0;
}

p {
  background-color: inherit;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  filter: invert(1) grayscale(1) contrast(9);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Testing</p>
</div>
```

You might find more information about it on the following website:
https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/

Comment: If the background is dark, shouldn't the text be white? That is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thats right, and that should work without a problem with the code above. Testing the extreme of #000 as background sets the text to white. Using e.g. #a00 as background also set the text color to white. Using e.g. #af0 as background, the text color is black, due to the bright background. Or have you tested the scenarios above and can't reproduce the result?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and simply pressing run code snippet has black text on background for me.

Comment: Thanks for the advise! I use firefox, the background-clip is only available with webkit in chrome. Added that line.